# Weapon Finesse and touch attacks

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, touch-attacks

Can I take the Weapon Finesse feat and use it to make melee touch attacks with Dex instead of Str?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, *Complete Arcane*, page 73:

> **Weapon Finesse:**
>   You can treat touch spells as light weapons and use your Dexterity modifier (instead of your Strength modifier) on your touch attack rolls with such spells.